# Unbound Data Grid View

Tags: datagrid, vb6

I have been trying to find a solution for this for a while but I've only managed to find junk on outdated forums.

I am using VB6 and I want to display data in a tabular form. I thought about using a DataGrid but I can't figure out how to add rows to the grid.

Note: The DataGrid is not bound to a recordset.

Is there any way to add the data to the GridView without storing it in a recordset. And is there a better VB6 control to use in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGrids are designed to be used bound to a data source, though it can be a custom data source object and not just an ADO Recordset.

For general display you might want to use the MSHFlexGrid (or the VB5 holdover MSFlexGrid).